# What is the best general way to pre-set username and password INPUT fields inside a Website loaded at TWebBrowser FMX

Tags: javascript, html, delphi, firemonkey, twebbrowser

What is the best method and general solution to get input fields username and password pre-set from inside an application for an loaded Website inside Delphi TWebBrowser FMX?
For example:

```
Var iuser,ipassword: String;
...
WebBrowser.URL := www.facebook.com;
WebBrowser.Navigate;
WebBrowser.EvaluateJavaScript(  '<script>' +
               'var e = document.getElementById("email");' +
               'e.value = "' +iuser+'";}' +
               'var s = document.getElementById("pass");' +
               's.value = "' +ipassword+'";}' +
                '</script>'
                );
```

The above way seems not to work (fields are empty and after calling code a second time causing error) and this way is even not general, because the ID for username and password will be different on most websites.

Comment: Try not appending `<script>`, just find and setup the element value.

Comment: Evaluate script in `OnDidFinishLoad` event.

Comment: WebBrowser.EvaluateJavaScript(
               'var user = "' + iuser + '";'+
               'var password = "' + ipassword + '";'+
               'addEventListener("onDidFinishLoad", function setInputs(user ,password){' +
               'var e = document.getElementById("email");' +
               'e.value = user;' +
               'var s = document.getElementById("pass");' +
               's.value = password;}'  );
I tried above, with and without <scrip>, but the fields will not be filled

Comment: I hope you are not storing the password in your database ;)

Comment: in encrypted way...